# Liquibase groovy accessomg datebaseChangeLog property

Tags: gradle, groovy, liquibase

I have the following Liquibase script written in Groovy.

```
package data.db

databaseChangeLog {

  // H2
  property(name: "date", value: "DATETIME", dbms: "h2")
  property(name: "integer", value: "INTEGER", dbms: "h2")
  property(name: "bigint", value: "BIGINT", dbms: "h2")
  property(name: "current_date", value: "NOW()", dbms: "h2")
  property(name: "current_timestamp", value: "NOW()", dbms: "h2")

  // TABLES
  include(file: "tables/2017-06-22-001-user-account-tables.groovy", relativeToChangelogFile: true)
}
```

I am using Gradle for build and I included `compile "org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:1.2.2"` so the script itself works.

However, I don't know how I can access these databaseChangeLog properties inside the script. I could't find and documentation or examples on how to do it.

Using xml it is pretty straightforward, here is the [documentation with an example](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changelog_parameters.html).

How do I do this using Groovy?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution that works, but seems a bit unwieldy. Please recommend something better if there is such a thing:

```
final DatabaseChangeLog dcl = (DatabaseChangeLog) properties['databaseChangeLog'];
final String bigintType = dcl.changeLogParameters.getValue("bigint", dcl)
```

Here is a bit of context:

```
package data.db.tables

import liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog

databaseChangeLog {

  final DatabaseChangeLog dcl = (DatabaseChangeLog) properties['databaseChangeLog'];
  final String bigintType = dcl.changeLogParameters.getValue("bigint", dcl)

  changeSet(id: "2017-06-22-001-user-account-tables", author: "goranmrzljak") {
    comment("User account tables")

    createTable(tableName: "user_account_permission") {
      column(name: "id", type: bigintType) {
        constraints(primaryKey: true, primaryKeyName: "user_account_permission_pk")
      }

      // ...
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

This works both in the same file or `databaseChangeLog`, or in a different file or `databaseChangeLog` from where the properties were defined.